# Append from 2.79 to 2.8

Tags: rendering

I made a sea with fluid simulation in blender 2.79 and I would like to append it in blender 2.8 but when I try it all my materials are burned, total white. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: you have to append thing per thing that you need in the scene such as materials,models,etc, simulations might not be compatible from 2.79 to 2.8...

Comment: Might want to make a copy and opne the copy of the file in 2.8?